# Delete confirmation using sweetalert in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, crud, delete-row, sweetalert

I manage to create delete method using

> $scope.filteredlist.splice(item,1);

but now i want to create delete method with sweetalert and when user click on 'yes' button, it's will delete data and if user click on 'cancel' button, it will return to the page.

The problem that i face is the delete method will work at the second click. Eg current page: click on delete button(trash icon) then click 'yes button' then click ok button then it not work but when try to click click again the trash icon button, it will delete it. I already link the sweetalert into the index.

So here is my maintenance.html

```
<div id="maintenance-main">
<div class="row card-content">
    <div class=" maintenance-box">
        <h3><strong>Maintenance</strong></h3>
    </div>

    <section ng-controller="maintenanceCtrl as panel">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified responsive-tabs">
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(1)}">
                <a href="" ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Project</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(2)}">
                <a href=""  ng-click="panel.selectTab(2)">Project Estimation</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(3)}">
                <a href=""  ng-click="panel.selectTab(3)">Timeline</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(4)}">
                <a href=""  ng-click="panel.selectTab(4)">Test Execution</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(5)}">
                <a href=""  ng-click="panel.selectTab(5)">Defect</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active:panel.isSelected(6)}">
                <a href=""  ng-click="panel.selectTab(6)">Status</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <div class="row step-content">
            <form>
               <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
                    <div maintenance-project><!--name of directive in js (MaintenanceProject) not same in html because AngularJS will handle translating the camel cased name when we define it to the snake case-->
                    </div>               
                </div>
                <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
                    <div maintenance-project-estimation>
                    </div>                 
                </div>
                <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(3)">
                    <div maintenance-timeline>
                    </div>                 
                </div> 
                <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(4)">
                    <div maintenance-test-execution>
                    </div>                 
                </div> 
                <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(5)">
                    <div maintenance-defect>
                    </div>                 
                </div> 
                <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(6)">
                    <div maintenance-status>
                    </div>                 
                </div> 

            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

This is maintenance.js

```
'use strict';app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('maintenance', {
        url: "/maintenance",
        views: {
            'navbar': {
                templateUrl: "components/qmc-header/qmc-header.html",
            },
            'content': {
                controller: "maintenanceCtrl",
                templateUrl: 'modules/maintenance/maintenance.html'
            }
        }
    })}]);
```

this is maintenance-ctrl.js

```
'use strict';app.controller('maintenanceCtrl', ["$scope",  function($scope) {
//this.tab=1 to show that the first view must in tab 1 which is project
this.tab=1;

this.selectTab = function (setTab){
    this.tab=setTab;
};
this.isSelected=function(checkTab){
    return this.tab==checkTab;
};}]);
```

maintenance-project.html

```
<ng-form name="projecttable"><div class="col-md-12 content-maintenance">
<h4>
    <strong>Project
    </strong>
</h4>
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control"   ng-model="filterproject" placeholder="FILTER" type="text"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span> Filter
    </span>
</div>
<br>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead >
            <tr>
                <th><i class="mandatory">*</i>PPMID</th>
                <th><i class="mandatory">*</i>EPRID</th>
                <th><i class="mandatory">*</i>Release ID</th>
                <th><i class="mandatory">*</i>Project Name</th>
                <th><i class="mandatory">*</i>Release Name</th>
                <th><i class="mandatory">*</i>Application Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="PPMID" name="ppmid" id="ppmid" type="number" min="1" placeholder="PPMID" ng-required="true" ng-class="{required: projecttable.ppmid.$invalid && projecttable.ppmid.$touched}" >
                    <div class="errormessage" ng-show="projecttable.ppmid.$invalid && projecttable.ppmid.$touched">
                        <span>Enter valid PPMID</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="EPRID" name="eprid" id="eprid" type="number" min="1" placeholder="EPRID" ng-required="true" ng-class="{required: projecttable.eprid.$invalid && projecttable.eprid.$touched}" >
                    <div class="errormessage" ng-show="projecttable.eprid.$invalid && projecttable.eprid.$touched">
                        <span>Enter valid EPRID</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" name="releaseid" ng-model="Releaseid" id="releaseid" type="text" placeholder="Release ID" ng-required="true" ng-class="{required: projecttable.releaseid.$invalid && projecttable.releaseid.$touched}" >
                    <div class="errormessage" ng-show="projecttable.releaseid.$invalid && projecttable.releaseid.$touched">
                        <span>Enter valid ReleaseID</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" name="projectname" ng-model="projectname" id="projectname" type="text" placeholder="Project Name" ng-required="true" ng-class="{required: projecttable.projectname.$invalid && projecttable.projectname.$touched}" >
                    <div class="errormessage" ng-show="projecttable.projectname.$invalid && projecttable.projectname.$touched">
                        <span>Enter valid Project Name</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" name="releasename" ng-model="releasename" id="releasename" type="text" placeholder="Release Name" ng-required="true" ng-class="{required: projecttable.releasename.$invalid && projecttable.releasename.$touched}" >
                    <div class="errormessage" ng-show="projecttable.releasename.$invalid && projecttable.releasename.$touched">
                        <span>Enter valid Release Name</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="form-control" name="appname" ng-model="appname" id="applicationname" type="text" placeholder="Application Name" ng-required="true" ng-class="{required: projecttable.appname.$invalid && projecttable.appname.$touched}" >
                    <div class="errormessage" ng-show="projecttable.appname.$invalid && projecttable.appname.$touched">
                        <span>Enter valid Application Name</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>

                    <button ng-click="addproject()" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="projecttable.$invalid || projecttable.$touched">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>                      
                    </button> 
                </th>  
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredlist | filter: filterproject" ng-include="loadTemplateproject(item)">

            </tr>   
            <!--orderBy=it will arrage the data, as default is is ascending. true:decending false:ascending| filter= allow to filter the table
            <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredlist | orderBy: 'PPMID' | filter:filterproject">
            <td>{{item.PPMID}}</td>
            <td>{{item.EPRID}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Releaseid}}</td>
            <td>{{item.projectname}}</td>
            <td>{{item.releasename}}</td>
            <td>{{item.appname}}</td>
            <td>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button>
                <button ng-click="remove()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
             </tr>-->
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="viewproject">
        <td>{{item.PPMID}}</td>
        <td>{{item.EPRID}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Releaseid}}</td>
        <td>{{item.projectname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.releasename}}</td>
        <td>{{item.appname}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="editContentproject(item)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button>
                <button ng-click="removeproject($index)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
        </td>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="editproject">
        <td> <input class="form-control" ng-model="editablerow.PPMID" id="ppmid" type="number" min="1" ></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="editablerow.EPRID" id="eprid" type="number" min="1" ></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="editablerow.Releaseid" id="releaseid" type="text" ></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="editablerow.projectname" id="projectname" type="text" ></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="editablerow.releasename" id="releasename" type="text"></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="editablerow.appname" id="applicationname" type="text" ></td>
        <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveDataproject($index)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                </button>
                <button ng-click="resetproject()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button> 
        </td>
    </script>


</div>
```

this is maintenance-project-directive.js

```
 app.directive('maintenanceProject', [function()  {
return{
  restrict: 'EA',
  scope: {},
  templateUrl: 'modules/maintenance/maintenance-project.html',
  link: function($scope, element, attrs) 
  {
    $scope.filteredlist=getdummydata ();
    $scope.editablerow = '';
    function getdummydata()
    {
        return [
        {

          PPMID:10101,
          EPRID:10201,
          Releaseid: 10301,
          projectname:'a',
          releasename:'b',
          appname:'c'
        },
        {  

          PPMID:40102,
          EPRID:40202,
          Releaseid: 40302,
          projectname:'d',
          releasename:'e',
          appname:'f'
        },
        {  

          PPMID:50103,
          EPRID:50203,
          Releaseid: 50303,
          projectname:'g',
          releasename:'h',
          appname:'i'
        },
        {  

          PPMID:60104,
          EPRID:60204,
          Releaseid: 60304,
          projectname:'j',
          releasename:'k',
          appname:'l'
        },
        {  

          PPMID:70105,
          EPRID:70205,
          Releaseid: 70305,
          projectname:'m',
          releasename:'n',
          appname:'o'
        },
        {  

          PPMID:80106,
          EPRID:80206,
          Releaseid: 80306,
          projectname:'p',
          releasename:'q',
          appname:'r'
        }];
    }
    $scope.addproject=function()
      { //use unshift to add item in beginning of array
        $scope.filteredlist.unshift(
              {
                 PPMID: $scope.PPMID,
                 EPRID:$scope.EPRID, 
                 Releaseid:$scope.Releaseid, 
                 projectname:$scope.projectname, 
                 releasename:$scope.releasename,
                 appname:$scope.appname
              });
        $scope.resetAll(); 
      }
    //to make its empty (reset back) for add
    $scope.resetAll = function()
      {
        $scope.filteredList = '' ; 
        $scope.PPMID = '';
        $scope.EPRID = '';
        $scope.Releaseid = '';
        $scope.projectname = ''; 
        $scope.releasename = ''; 
        $scope.appname = '';
      }  

       //remove utk delete whole row (gmbr trash)
       $scope.removeproject=function(item){

          swal({
          title: "Proceed to delete the selected record?",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
          confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete!",
          cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          closeOnCancel: false
          },
          function(isConfirm){
            if(isConfirm){
              $scope.filteredlist.splice(item,1);
              swal("deleted!","Your file is deleted/.", "success");
              }
            else{
              swal("Cancelled!", "Cancelled");
              return 'viewproject';
            }

          });
       }
    /*$scope.removeproject=function(item)
      {
        $scope.filteredlist.splice(item,1);
      }*/
    //for edit function
    $scope.editContentproject=function(item)
      {
         $scope.editablerow=angular.copy(item);//now edittablerow hold value item id=..
      }
    $scope.loadTemplateproject= function(item)
      {
        if(item.Releaseid===$scope.editablerow.Releaseid) return 'editproject';
        else
          return 'viewproject';
      }
    $scope.saveDataproject = function (indx)
    {
      $scope.filteredlist[indx] = angular.copy($scope.editablerow);
      $scope.resetproject();
    }
    //ni reset for cancel 
    $scope.resetproject=function(){
      $scope.editablerow=[];
    }

  }
}; }])
```

Please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: What is `swal`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko based on my understanding. swal is needed to in building the alert box using sweetalert. It kinda the syntax.

Comment: Well, just try add `$scope.$applyAsync` after `$scope.filteredlist.splice(item,1);`. Like this `$scope.filteredlist.splice(item,1); $scope.$applyAsync()`;

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko it works like cham. But can you explain why need to used  $scope.$applyAsync(); . It really will help others in future

Comment: I can't explain it here. Read this [article](https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes). Mistake **#10**.

Comment: thanks @StepanKasyanenko